# Double q-analog of Pochhammer

Tags: nt.number-theory, special-functions, integrable-systems, q-analogs, difference-equations

Has the function
$$(z;q_1,q_2)_\infty := \prod_{n_1,n_2=0}^\infty (1-z \, q_1^{n_1} q_2^{n_2}), \quad |q_1|,|q_2|<1$$
been studied in the math literature? For example, does it obey any difference equation similar to the quantum dilogarithm, or have some modular properties? The only place I see it, is the theory of elliptic Gamma function.

One reference I found is this paper about integrable systems in physics: [Mironov, Morozov, and Zenkevich - Duality in elliptic Ruijsenaars system and elliptic symmetric functions](https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-021-09248-9).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This product appears in permutation enumeration. See, for example, D. P. Roselle, [Coefficients associated with the expansion of certain products](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2040625) ([DOI](https://doi.org/10.2307/2040625)), Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 45 (1974), 144-150.